# Creating Common Http service wrapper in angular 6 is good or not

Tags: angular

I have created a common http service wrapper and I inject it in every component. I am little bit confused with is,

is it better to inject HttpClient Service in every component or to create a http service wrapper as I have created one?

Or we can do both?

Please give some suggestion on this. That will be really helpful.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
import { LoaderService } from './loader.service';
import { FormUtils } from '../utils/form.utils';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
  private apiUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _loaderService: LoaderService) {
    this.apiUrl = environment.url;
  }

  post<T>(url, data, loader = true): Observable<Common.ApiResponse<T>> {
    if (loader) {
      this._loaderService.loader.next(loader);
    }
    return this.http.post<Common.ApiResponse<T>>(this.apiUrl + url, data);
  }

  put<T>(url, data, loader = true): Observable<Common.ApiResponse<T>> {
    if (loader) {
      this._loaderService.loader.next(loader);
    }
    return this.http.put<Common.ApiResponse<T>>(this.apiUrl + url, data);
  }

  patch<T>(url, data, loader = true): Observable<Common.ApiResponse<T>> {
    if (loader) {
      this._loaderService.loader.next(loader);
    }
    return this.http.patch<Common.ApiResponse<T>>(this.apiUrl + url, data);
  }

  get<T>(
    url,
    httpParams?: any,
    loader = true
  ): Observable<Common.ApiResponse<T>> {
    const updatedParams = this.parseDateToTimeStamp(httpParams);
    console.log(updatedParams, '--------------');

    if (loader) {
      this._loaderService.loader.next(loader);
    }
    for (let item in httpParams) {
      if (
        httpParams[item] === '' ||
        httpParams[item] === undefined ||
        httpParams[item] === null
      ) {
        delete httpParams[item];
      }
    }
    const header = {};
    if (httpParams) {
      header['params'] = updatedParams;
    }
    return this.http.get<Common.ApiResponse<T>>(this.apiUrl + url, header);
  }

  parseDateToTimeStamp(obj: any) {
    const newValueInstance = Object.assign({}, obj);
    (function isEmpty(data: any): boolean {
      if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
          data.forEach((item: any, index: number) => {
            if (isEmpty(item)) {
              data.splice(index, 1);
            }
          });
        } else {
          Object.keys(data).map((key, index) => {
            console.log(data[key] instanceof Date);
            if (data[key] instanceof Date) {
              data[key] = new Date(data[key]).getTime();
            }
          });
        }
      }
      return data;
    })(newValueInstance);
    return newValueInstance;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is my opinion that it is a good practice, especially if I think I only inject it into a state manager, but obviously it's just my opinion, so, your question is opinion based and off topic on so, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I really wouldn't advise on doing that **unless you know what you are doing** ...

Also, if you are creating this wrapper service simply for loader service. Consider using an angular interceptor instead. The interceptor will detect when a http request is made and displays out your loader. Have a read on this medium article/guide: [Loader Bar on Every HTTP Request in Angular 6](https://medium.com/@zeljkoradic/loader-bar-on-every-http-request-in-angular-6-60d8572a21a9)

Currently, your "wrapper" only allows url link, HttpParams, body and a loader variable  to be passed in as arguments. You will start facing problems when you have to integrate other API endpoints that require specific `HttpHeaders` to be set or has a different `responseType` like 'text'. **You'd end up having to modify your wrapper service again and again and wasting a lot of time just to save a few lines of code.**

Or you could just be trying to do a simple get request without wanting to call `parseDateToTimeStamp()`. You can't do that with your *wrapper service*.

Or, what if you want to do a `HEAD` request, then you'd end up having to modify your *wrapper service* or using a mixture of your *wrapper service* and the original `HttpClient` package in your app which, imo, just code smell.

You're better off just using HttpClient package as it is.

Instead, you can create a new .ts file, probably name it as `DateTimeHelper.ts` or something and export your `parseDateToTimeStamp()` out in it like this:

`export function parseDateToTimeStamp(){}`

Then import this function in whatever service functions that you need to use.

In doing so, you will need to abstract out the following part of your code into a separate function also (something like this):

```js
export function updateMyParams(httpParams: HttpParams){ //or some identifier that you prefer
    const updatedParams = this.parseDateToTimeStamp(httpParams);
    console.log(updatedParams, '--------------');

    if (loader) {
      this._loaderService.loader.next(loader);
    }
    for (let item in httpParams) {
      if (
        httpParams[item] === '' ||
        httpParams[item] === undefined ||
        httpParams[item] === null
      ) {
        delete httpParams[item];
      }
    }
    const header = {};
    if (httpParams) {
      header['params'] = updatedParams;
    }
}
```

You'd only then have to re-import these 2 functions for services that you need to use it.

Comment: So @terahertz, according to you, no need to create httpservice. We should use HttClient Service provided by angular itself in every component and add headers , body, params everything from component. So  i was thinking to reduce these lines in every component by creating a service.

Comment: Assume you have two services, AuthService and ProductsService. These services define methods that return HttpClient _observables_. When you return a `this.httpClient.get(url)`, you are returning an observable. Components inject these services and _subscribes_ to services' methods (Observables) to call API. The action of subscribing causes the HTTP request to be fired. If you need to define HttpParams or Headers, you can always define them at service-level. Not Component-level. Are you sure you need a wrapper httpservice to do that? If it's required by ur use case, u can design it that way ofc.

Comment: I had done the same thing before, a Http Wrapper Service that wrapped around HttpClient. I did it because one of the first online courses in Angular that I took recommended doing it. As I became more familiar with Angular, I went back to the same course and it turned out it was for the old Http package, not HttpClient package. I faced the many problems that I have shared with you in my answer.. To the point we simply discarded the wrapper service and use HttpClient.

Comment: @terahertz thanks for you detail answer, I would like your comments on this approach https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/262826/are-there-technical-issues-disavdantages-on-this-baseservice-that-aims-to-simpli